# lambda failed on C++14/17 and works on later version

Tags: lambda, c++17, c++20

I have a priority queue definition got failed on C++14/17 but works with the later standard.
Would anyone tell me why?

```
    auto compare = [](const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2) {
        return p1.second < p2.second;
    };

    // compile failure on C++ 14/17 
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(compare)> pq;
```

May I ask a future question? Why the first case with lambda is fine but the second is wrong:

```
auto comp = [&](const pair<string,int>& a, const pair<string,int>& b) {
    return a.second > b.second || (a.second == b.second && a.first < b.first);
};
// OK!!!
// typedef priority_queue< pair<string,int>, vector<pair<string,int>>, decltype(comp)> my_priority_queue_t;
// my_priority_queue_t  pq(comp);

// BOMB!!!
priority_queue< pair<string,int>, vector<pair<string,int>>, decltype(comp)> pq;
```

Comment: Before c++20 lambdas were not default-constructible.

Comment: Just complementing @rafix07 comment, the third template parameter of `std::priority_queue` receives a type, and not a value. Then internally `std::priority_queue` will create a lambda from that type. This is only possible since  C++20 version, where lambdas where allowed to be default constructible. In fact, I think this particular use case was the main motivation to make lambdas default constructible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the following constructor of `priority_queue`:

> `priority_queue() : priority_queue(Compare(), Container()) { }`

from [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue). As you can see it calls `Compare()` - default constructor of comparator which in your case is closure type. But before C++20 closures were not default constructible. That is why this overload of constructor doesn't work.

Since C++20 this all is fine because closures have:

> ```
> ClosureType() = default;
> (since C++20)(only if no captures are specified)
> ```

from [lambdas reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).